# Kernel of Spherically Symmetric Diffusion Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I'm trying to find the Kernel of the 3D Diffusion Equation but my lecture notes are unclear on the procedure.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D \nabla ^2u$$
$$u(\vec{x}, 0) = R(|\vec{x}|)$$

I need to show that the solutions might be written as:
$$u(|\vec{x}|, t) = \int ^{+\infty}_0 dr r^2 R(r)K(r, |\vec{x}|; t)$$
where $K$ is the kernel which I also need to find explicitly.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I started by transforming the equation: $\frac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial t} = -Dk^2\tilde{u} \Leftrightarrow \tilde{u}(k,t) = \tilde{u}(k,0)\exp(-Dk^2t)$

Then using Radial / Spherical Polar Fourier Transform:
$$u(x,t) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^{+\infty}_0k^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr}\tilde{u}(k,t)dk = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^{+\infty}_0k^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr}\tilde{u}(k,0)\exp{(-Dk^2t)}dk$$
$$u(x,t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int^{+\infty}_0k^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr}\exp{(-Dk^2t)}dk\int^{+\infty}_0r^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr}R(r)dr$$
$$u(x,t) = \int^{+\infty}_0r^2R(r)K(r, |\vec{x}|;t)dr$$

where here the kernel is: $\frac{2}{\pi}\int^{+\infty}_{0}k^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{k^2r^2}\exp{(-Dk^2t)}dk$

I don't know how to handle the integral and I don't even know if what I am doing is good.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh I heard about that, would you say what I ended up with is the Heat Kernel?

Comment: You can cancel $k^2$ first and then use complex analysis to handle the integral.